# Why only reference type variables are stored in Memory in Solidity

Tags: blockchain, solidity

i'm new to Solidity, I read a lot of blogs but still i'm having a hard time in understanding why only reference-type variables like string, array, struct are stored in memory and not value-type variable like uint?

Answer (score 0):

You can also store value types in memory. They don't require explicit statement of the data location, as it's always implicitly defined by whether it's a property or a variable.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8;

contract MyContract {
    int number = 100; // implicit `storage` location of a property

    function foo() public {
        int anotherNumber = 100; // implicit `memory` location of a variable
    }
}
```

On the other hand, a reference type can be a `memory` value, a pointer to a `storage` property, as well as a pointer to a part of the function input (`calldata`). That's why you need to explicitly define data location of reference types.